# Firebase facebook auth error

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am getting a problem with the [cordova facebook authentication plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) when using it to login using Firebase Auth.

Here is my error:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
if (window.facebookConnectPlugin && (window.cordova && device.platform == 'iOS') || (window.cordova && device.platform == 'Android')) {
        console.log("using the plugin");
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile'], function(result) {
          provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.authResponse.accessToken);
          provider.addScope('public_profile');
          provider.addScope('email');
          Auth.firebaseAuth.$signInWithCredential(provider).then(function(authData) {
            // User successfully logged in
            console.debug(authData);
            console.log("logged in ionic");
          }).catch(errFn);
        }, errFn);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I needed to add an Android app over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/295381890832215/settings/), then generate a key hash and input that using this command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias <alias> -keystore <path to app keystore> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`